# Does packing bools alongside addresses reduce storage costs?

Tags: solidity, gas, storage

Say I have a struct like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    bool foo;
    uint256 bar;
    uint256 baz;
    address qux;
}
```

If I rewrite it like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    bool foo;
    address qux;
    uint256 bar;
    uint256 baz;
}
```

Would storage become less expensive, since `address` is an alias for `uint160` and `bool` can only be 0 or 1? What if `foo` was of type `address`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does for the first case but if `foo` is an `address`, no, there are no storage efficiency gains.

If I apply the changes mentioned in the question body, I end up spending a **whopping 20,134 less gas** for adding a new struct in the mapping.

See transactions on Rinkeby:

- [Without Tight Packing ~ 109,607 gas](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x0b284644d2566467010179438b0fd42756baf5027f804c2b27f5b67a58057370)
- [With Tight Packing ~ 89,473 gas](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x8b84c586663f345292be8f80de5ee4ed605efe3aea9eedc862eae38c63048857)

The example contract used:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.11;

contract StorageCostTest {

    struct MyStruct {
        bool foo;
        uint256 bar;
        uint256 baz;
        address qux;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => MyStruct) private myStructs;
    uint256 public nextMyStructId;

    constructor() public {
        nextMyStructId = 1;
    }

    function addItem(bool foo, uint256 bar, uint256 baz, address qux) external {
        myStructs[nextMyStructId] = MyStruct({
           foo: foo,
           bar: bar,
           baz: baz,
           qux: qux
        });
        nextMyStructId += 1;
    }
}
```